# Pandas- How to check if list of strings in DF row contains any of strings in series in another DF?

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame that in one of columns contains lists of strings, like this one:

```
print(df_1.lists)
```

out:

```
0      [Pucku, Byłam, Miruś, Funkcjonariusze]
1      [Greger, Pytam, Jana, Dopóki, Wiary]
2      [Baborowa, Chcę, Innym, Baborowie]
etc
```

And I have another DataFrame, that in a Series contains words:

```
print(df_2.check)
```

out:

```
0                   Olszany
1                    Pucków
2                  Baborowa
3                Studzionki
4                     Pytam
5                  Lasowice
etc
```

I want to take each row of `df_1.lists` and check if list contains any of words from `df_2.check`. If it contains, then I'd like to assign those contained words to a column in `df_1.lists`. How to do it?

[EDIT]  I tried df_1.lists.apply(lambda x:[list(set(df_2.checks.str.extract(r"("+ i +r")").dropna().values)) for i in x])  but this is waaaay too slow.

Comment: Interesting problem. Can you show us your latest attempt(s) by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52165617/edit)?

Comment: Hi, It is Stackoverflow policy to show your attempt. Please go through it and show your attempt in the question.

Comment: added my attempt in [EDIT]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension:

```
df_1['new'] = [[y for y in x if y in df_2['check'].values] for x in df_1['lists']]
```

Or get `intersection` between set and list for each value:

```
df_1['new'] = [list(set(x).intersection(df_2['check'])) for x in df_1['lists']]
```

Similar `intersection` between sets:

```
s = set(df_2['check'])
df_1['new'] = [list(set(x).intersection(s)) for x in df_1['lists']]
```